# How to display the image in power apps gallery from sharepoint list,where the image is in image format in sharepoint list

Tags: canvas, powerapps, sharepoint-list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DLj6.jpg)Is it possible to display images in power apps gallery ,where the image is stored in sharepoint list as image format.

Answer (score 0):

You have an Image Control in PowerApps. You can assign your Image from the datasource to the Image property of your ImageControl. So yes, it is possible.

Comment: I didnt get you.